# Using NGINX + Socket.io while specifying socket room/namespace

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, nginx, socket.io

I just updated a node+socket app to use https.  It took a while, but I now have a working nginx, node.js, socket.io configuration here.  It works great, but my question is, is it possible to configure the server side so that the client doesn't need to submit the `path` parameter, or at least include it as part of the url?  I'd like to be able to give users just a url to use, for example, `https://mywebsite.com/apiPath/myNamespace`.

Currently:

NGINX CONFIG:

```
upstream websocket1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
} 
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name         mywebsite.com;
        ssl_certificate     this.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key this.pem;
        location /apiPath/ {
                proxy_pass http://websocket1/socket.io/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

SERVER:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.listen(port);

var nsp = io.of('/myNamespace');

nsp.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
});
```

CLIENT:

`var socket = require('socket.io-client')(https://mywebsite.com/myNamespace, {path: '/apiPath'});`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to not use the path parameter, but the path is the namespace. If you don't supply one, it just uses a namespace of `/`. If you only need the one namespace, that should be fine. Instead of specifying `.of()` on your `io` calls, you can simply do `io.to()` and it will use the default namespace

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Unfortunately I do need to use multiple namespaces (or at least I think I do...maybe months from now when I understand sockets and NGINX better, I'll realize how absurd my current setup is).  Anyway, I was able to find a solution here:

https://fadeit.dk/blog/2015/05/21/socketio-namespaces-and-nginx/

With this location syntax, I'm able to just use the following in my client:

`var socket = require('socket.io-client')(https://mywebsite.com/myNamespace);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to my issue [here](https://fadeit.dk/blog/2015/05/21/socketio-namespaces-and-nginx/).  With this new setup, I don't need to pass a `path` parameter and can use namespaces as part of my url.  My revised setup looks like this:

NGINX CONFIG:

```
upstream websocket1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
} 
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name         mywebsite.com;
        ssl_certificate     this.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key this.pem;
        location ~(myNamespace|socket\.io).*$ {
                proxy_pass http://websocket1;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

SERVER:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
http.listen(port);

var nsp = io.of('/myNamespace');

nsp.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
});
```

CLIENT:

`var socket = require('socket.io-client')(https://mywebsite.com/myNamespace);`